# MacOS standard Apple email client, incoming mail arrives in trash folder. How to stop this?

Tags: email, macos, imap, trash

Apologies if this is the wrong place to ask.  (Can you suggest a better one?)

I'm setting up a brand new Macbook Air (Oct 2022) for an older neighbor.
The ISP is att.net

The email protocol is standard SMTP, and the server is smtp.mail.att.net .

One quirk: AT&T uses OAuth to verify client connections, and they have a page telling you to set up a "secure key" to access your email.  The webpage describing that is https://www.att.com/support/article/email-support/KM1240308/.  I did that for the old Macbook that this new one is going to replace.   And carried it forward to the new Macbook, which does support OAuth in the current email client, but I left the OAuth avoidance procedure in place.

The problem (on both old and new Macbooks) is that incoming email arrives in the Trash folder instead of in the Inbox folder.  I was on the phone with AT&T support in the Phillipines for an hour before I finally realized that they knew nothing whatever about email on any level, but would be nice to me for as long as it took for that to sink in.

We've been moving all the incoming email into the Inbox manually and everything works perfectly from there.  Any ideas on how to fix this?

I set up a test account (with neighbor's credentials) on a different Apple computer, and the new test email account has exactly the same problem.  Next I will try removing the OAuth avoidance protocol and reverting to the older process.

Web searches reveal that other people have hit this issue, but no good remedy has been found so far.
Help!

Comment: SMTP is for sending mail; for receiving, you should be using either IMAP (better) or POP (worse). It looks like you can also get/check AT&T mail [via the web](https://www.att.com/support/article/email-support/KM1010436), so the first test I'd try is exiting the Apple Mail client (so it's not accessing the mailbox at all), send them a message, then check it in the webmail interface and see if it appears in the inbox or the trash. If it's in the inbox, check it in Apple Mail and see if it shows as moved in the web interface as well. This isolates whether its actually Apple Mail moving it.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info - yes, she's using IMAP (is anyone still stuck on POP3?).    We tried the experiment, and the emails show up in the Trash on the webmail interface too!   In webmail there is actually a way to select all mails in bulk, and then there is a button to move them to the Inbox.   If you do that, the mails still arrive at the Trash in the Apple email client.   Thanks for any suggestions.   This behavior makes it seem more likely that the deviancy is not necessarily at the Apple end of things.

Comment: Yeah, if it's moving them to trash with Apple Mail not running, that pretty much means it's something on the server (some automatic processing rule or something?)... unless there's another client somewhere accessing the same mailbox?

Comment: Do all emails land in the Trash folder, or just those from selected senders? If it's the former there's a misconfiguration on the receiver (either AT&T or a rule associated with your account). If it's the latter then it's more likely to be a misconfiguration for the sender and AT&T is treating the emails as forgeries (or whatever)

Comment: Thx for the quality answers.  Apple support solved it.  Apple person wrote "At the ISP (ATT) account, some filters were mistakenly added to her email that caused all of her inboxed messages go to the trash. Once we removed them, everything is working perfectly."      I didn't see those filters when I logged into the ISP a/c, and I don't know who changed them, but I'll log in and review them soon to learn more.  ATT support line was completely worthless on this (and I suspect other tech problems) Thanks again, Gordon.

Answer (score 1):

Apple person looked into this (she did not have to!) and reported "At the ISP (ATT) account, some filters were mistakenly added to her email that caused all of her inboxed messages go to the trash."

"Once we removed them, everything is working perfectly."

Major kudos to Apple support! Major raspberries to the worthless AT&T "support" line who kept me talking for an hour without offering even so much as a suggestion of items to review or things to try to narrow down the problem.  Don't use AT&T as your ISP if you might ever need support.  They outsourced support to the cheapest bidder, and they know nothing.